# Resize UITableViewCell (created from xib) height according to subview height

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, xib

I'm able to resize superiew height depending on subview height by setting up the follwing constraints as shown:

[image: SuperView Constraints]]

[image: SubView Constraints]

I want to achieve the same effect in UITableViewCell i created from xib. But i it not happening. I have setup the same constraints shown in the pictures for my UITableViewCell. Is there some thing special i need to do to resize UITableViewCell resize itself according to subview height?

Comment: Yes you should use UITableViewAutomaticDimension :
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

If you set constraints correctly and your subview size change, it will update row height dynamically
Great article here https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: That i know, i will do that in the code. What i want to see is in the xib, when subview height changes, the cell's content view and cell height itslef also changes. As shown in the pictures attached.

Comment: Ok I see what you want to achieve. Can you show the constraint you defined in your tableviewcell's xib please ?

Comment: @aximem 
https://imgur.com/a/HwD4O
These are my constraints. What i want to achieve is when i hide the orange view on rum time the cell resize itself to the szie of blackview.

Comment: Edited to inline images into original question

Answer (score 1):

Design ui in TableViewCell in xib and not in view. For dynamic cell height according to subview add leading trailing top bottom constraint. dont add height constraint. 
In view controller containing tableview instance put code

```
 mytableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  mytableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
```

Comment: I have to add height constraints because i'm adding three subviews to the UITableViewCell content view. If i don't add height constraints, it gives error for not adding height or Y constraint.

Comment: try to remove error without adding constant height constraint. add top constraint to view not to layout guide. set comparative height(praportional to superview or praportional equal to other subview) of subviews or set diffrent vertical content hugging priority to them.

Comment: imgur.com/a/HwD4O

These are my constraint. I want the the cell to resize itself to blackview when i hide the orange view programmatically on run time.

Comment: to resolve ambiguity u need to clear cell height to system. if black view has subviews then adding constraint to subview will clear the black view height to system, if you dont have any subview to black view then you need to specify height constraint to blackview. for manipulating orange view height u need to add height constraint and its outlet to view controller so that you can change constant. Programatic frame change wont go well with autolayout. you need to do one of this combination.
Set 1) Orange view heigth + cell height
2) set black view height + cell heigt
3) set both view height

Answer (score 0):

You have to set rowHeight like this:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250w
```